# How to get widget object from ttk.Notebook tab?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have notebook widget of class ttk.Notebook. In this notebook I'm adding many tabs:

`notebook.add(child=my_object, text='my tab')`

How can I get tab object and not tab name?

## UPDATE 1

So, there is children dictionary. OK that brings next problem.

What I really want to do is to take my hands on object of active tab in Notebook. So I have this:

```
notebook.children[notebook.select().split('.')[2]])
```

but it looks ugly. Unfortunately widget name returned by select() has not exactly same format as widget names in children[]. Is there any method of reliable translation of one format to another or split() will never fail in this situation?

This is demo of problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        notebook = Notebook(self)
        notebook.add(child=Frame(notebook), text='tab1')
        notebook.add(child=Frame(notebook), text='tab2')
        notebook.add(child=Frame(notebook), text='tab3')
        notebook.pack()

        print('Tabs are: ', notebook.children.keys())
        print('Active tab: ', notebook.select())
        print(type(notebook.children[notebook.select().split('.')[2]]))

App().mainloop()
```

Comment: assign `my_object` to variable and use this variable.

Answer (score 6):

The `notebook.tabs()` call returns a list of "tab names" which correspond to the children widget objects.  A call to `someWidget.nametowidget(tab_name)` resolves to the child widget associated with that tab.

In other words, the Notebook `.tabs()` method returns a list of the names of the Notebook's children.

For your UPDATE:

The same as above applies, only now it's:

```
active_object = notebook.nametowidget(notebook.select())
```

Different versions of Python use different naming conventions, so using `nametowidget()` is the better way to go rather than manually processing the name to get the desired key to use for a reference into the children dict.

Answer (score 1):

ttk.Notebook stores Tab-Objects within it's children attribute which is a python dictionary like:

```
{my_tab._name: tab_object} e.g. {'4465111168': <Viewer.Tab object .4435079856.4465020320.4465111168>}
```

You can access a Tab-object via:

```
my_notebook.children[my_tab._name]
```

Where my_notebook is an instance of an ttk.Notebook object and my_tab is your Tab object. The tab attribute `_name` is the value wich get's stored as the key in `my_notebook.children`.

So the easiest way of accessing the tab objects would be by separately storing your `my_tab._name` values in a list or variable.
With all the names stored you can access the children dict like above.

See https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html for more reference.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted my former post, because it was basically bs.

To get the actual widget-object use the following code:

```
name =  mywidget.winfo_name() # this returns this ominous string
                              # of numbers and dots

object_from_name = mywidget._nametowidget(name) # this returns your
                                                # actual widget
```

If you print object_from_name you'll likely get the name. But I think, this is how tkinter widget objects are represented.
You should be able to do

```
object_from_name.config(text="stuff", do_further_stuff_here="")
```

Comment: The widget name (.234567890.1234567.123456689.354567) seems to be the complete tree beginning from your root-object.

Answer (score -1):

That's what did the trick for me:

```
for name in notebook.tabs():
    tab_widget = notebook.nametowidget(name)
```