# Get text from ScrolledText inside a Notebook widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code below where you can create tabs upon clicking button on menu. Also, there's a print button that prints all the contents of all the tabs.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()


class F(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    self.master.resizable(False,False)


    self.tab = Notebook(root)
    self.tab.grid(row=1, column=33, columnspan=10, rowspan=50, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NS')

    self.mb = Menu( root )
    root.config( menu=self.mb )
    self.sub_mb = Menu( self.mb, tearoff=0 )
    self.mb.add_command( label='create tab', command = self.create_tab )
    self.mb.add_command( label='print', command=self.print_contents_of_all_tabs )

    def create_tab(self):
        self.new_tab = ScrolledText(height=20, width=50)
        self.tab.add( self.new_tab, text='tab' )

    **# this should print the contents inside all the tabs**
    def print_contents_of_all_tabs(self):
        all_tabs = self.tab.tabs()            # get frame name of all tabs
        for x in range(len(all_tabs)):
            print(self.tab.index(all_tabs[x])) # print the index using frame name
            print(self.new_tab.get(1.0, END))  # This prints only the content of recently created tab

def main():
    F().mainloop()

main()
```

Now, I want to print all the contents of all the tabs using def print_contents_of_all_tabs(self). I already got the index of all tabs but I don't know how to use each index to get the text per tab. Also, if I use self.new_tab.get(1.0, END), It takes only the contents inside the recently created tab.

Say I have 3 tabs, first tab contains "this is first tab", second contains "this is second tab" and lastly third tab contains "this is the third tab". When I click print, the output from the code above would be like

```
0   # index of first tab
this is the third tab

1    # index of second tab
this is the third tab

2    # index of third tab
this is the third tab
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011264/how-to-get-widget-object-from-ttk-notebook-tab) which explains widget retrieval:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = Tk()


class F(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        root.geometry("500x500")
        self.master.resizable(False,False)


        self.tab = Notebook(root)
        self.tab.grid(row=1, column=33, columnspan=10, rowspan=50, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NS')

        self.mb = Menu( root )
        root.config( menu=self.mb )
        self.sub_mb = Menu( self.mb, tearoff=0 )
        self.mb.add_command( label='create tab', command = self.create_tab )
        self.mb.add_command( label='print', command=self.print_contents_of_all_tabs )

    def create_tab(self):
        new_tab = ScrolledText(height=20, width=50)
        self.tab.add( new_tab, text='tab' )

    def print_contents_of_all_tabs(self):
        # this should print the contents inside all the tabs**
        all_tabs = self.tab.tabs()            # get frame name of all tabs
        for x in range(len(all_tabs)):
            print(self.tab.index(all_tabs[x])) # print the index using frame name
            frame = self.tab._nametowidget(all_tabs[x])
            scrolled_text = frame.winfo_children()[1]
            print(scrolled_text.get(1.0, END))  # This prints the content of the tab

def main():
    F().mainloop()

main()
```